# How to implement array of stacks in c++?

Tags: c++, stack

Imagine a stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it might topple. Therefore, in real life, we would likely start a new stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. Implement a data structure *SetOfStacks* that mimics this. *SetOfStacks* should be composed of several stacks and should create a new stack once the previous one exceeds capacity. *SetOfStacks.push()* and *SetOfStacks.pop()* should behave identically to a single stack (that is, pop( ) should return the same values as it would if there were just a single stack). 
Implement a function popAt( int index) which performsa pop operation on a specific sub-stack.

Comment: What work have you done?  What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

There are several requirements. First we shall create a data structure that contains several other stacks. For this we will define a class.

We will use a `std::vector` that will hold as many `std::stack`s as needed. We add a also a variable, which will define the maximum stacksize for all `std::stack` in the `std::vector` of `std::stack`s.

Then we shall implement 3 functions. We start with the `push` function. That is fairly simple.

First, we check, is there are enough substacks. If there is no substack at all (the `std::vector` is `empty`), or, if the last existing `std::stack` is full (`size` is greater than our internal defined `maxStackSize`), then we add a complete new `std::stack` to our `std::vector`. After that, regardless if we have added a new `std::stack` before or not, we simply `push` the requested value on the last `std::stack` in our `std::vector`.

The other 2 functions are the `pop` functions. There is a general `pop` function and a `popAt`, which shall pop from a specific substack. If we think about it, then we can find out that the general function is a special case of the `popAt` function, with the index being that of the last stack. We will then simply call  `popAt(stacks.size() - 1)`.

Ok, then we concentrate on the `popAt` function.

First, we perform a boundary stack. That will emit an error message, if the index is negative (Can happen with calling `pop` on an empty `std:vector`, or, if the index is greater than the number of existing `std::stack`s.

Then, we check, if the required substack has data or is empty. If it is empty, we will remove it from the `std::vector` and decrement the index.

Independent from the previous action, we check again, if data is available. The index may be negative now, because we maybe have removed a `std::stack`. But also the `std::vector` maybe empty now. Or, also the addressed `stack` maybe `empty`. In all this cases, we display an error message.

Otherwise, we return a value from the `std::stack` with the current index.

In `main` I added some driver test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using MyType = int;
constexpr size_t DefaultMaxStackSize = 3;

class SetOfStacks {
    // The class data
    // The maximum size of one stack
    size_t maxStackSize{ DefaultMaxStackSize };

    // And a vector of stacks
    std::vector<std::stack<MyType>> stacks{};

public:

    // Constructor
    SetOfStacks() {}

    // 2nd Constructor for setting the stack size.
    explicit SetOfStacks(const size_t mss) : maxStackSize(mss) {};

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Simple push function
    void push(MyType mt) {

        // If there are no stacks at all, or the last stack is full
        if (stacks.empty() || stacks.back().size() >= maxStackSize) {

            // At a new stack
            stacks.emplace_back(std::stack<MyType>{});
        }

        // Add a value to the last stack
        stacks.back().push(mt);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Pop functions
    // STandard pop will call popAt with the index being the last avaliable stack
    MyType pop() { return popAt(stacks.size() - 1); }

    // Main working functions with error checking
    MyType popAt(int index) {

        // Here we will retrun the result
        MyType result{};

        // Sanity check. Is the index in the correct range
        if (index >= stacks.size()) {

            // Index is out of bounds. Inform user
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error:Wrong index. No data\n";
        }
        else {
            // So, now, index is in bounds. Check, if the stack at the specified index is empty
            if (stacks[index].empty()) {
                
                // Stack at specified index was empty. Remove it and decrement index
                stacks.pop_back();
                --index;
            }
            // Sanity check. There must be data available
            if (stacks.empty() || index < 0 || stacks[index].empty()) {
                // If not, inform the user
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Not data available\n";
            }
            else {
                // Return value from stack
                result = stacks[index].top();
                stacks[index].pop();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create a Ste of stacks
    SetOfStacks sos;

    // Populate it
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; ++i)
        sos.push(i);

    // Get all values from stack
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; ++i)
        std::cout << sos.pop() << '\n';

    // Get an additional value. Will of course not work
    std::cout << '\n' << sos.pop() << "\n\n";

    // Populate stack again
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; ++i)
        sos.push(i);

    // Get data from a specified stack
    std::cout << '\n' << sos.popAt(1) << "\n\n";

    // Get all values from stack. Will result in error for last 
    // element, becuase we already removed 1 element
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; ++i)
        std::cout << sos.pop() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```